# What am I doing wrong in this QBO v3 API (IPP) Attachments upload python request?

Tags: python-requests, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Intuit offers [these instructions](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/attachments#Request_Body) for uploading attachments (which become [Attachable objects](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/attachable) that can be associated with one or more transactions).

I **believe** I'm using python's requests module (via [rauth's OAuth1Session module](http://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#oauth-1-0-sessions)—see below for how I'm creating the session object) to generate these requests. Here's the code leading up to the request:

```
print request_type
print url
print headers
print request_body

r = session.request(request_type, url, header_auth,
                    self.company_id, headers = headers,
                    data = request_body, **req_kwargs)

result = r.json()

print json.dumps(result, indent=4)
```

and the output of these things:

```
POST
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/0123456789/upload
{'Accept': 'application/json'}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Invoice 003"; filename="Invoice 003.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
<@INCLUDE */MyDir/Invoice 003.pdf*@>
{
 "Fault": {
  "type": "SystemFault", 
  "Error": [
   {
    "Message": "An application error has occurred while processing your request", 
    "code": "10000", 
    "Detail": "System Failure Error: Cannot consume content type"
   }
  ]
 }, 
 "time": "[timestamp]"
}
```

I have confirmed (by uploading an attachment through the QBO web UI and then querying the Attachable object through the API) that application/pdf is included in the list of acceptable file types.

At sigmavirus24's suggestion, I tried removing the Content-Type line from the headers, but I got the same result.

Here's how I'm creating the session object (which, again, is working fine for other QBO v3 API requests of every type you see in Intuit's API Explorer):

```
from rauth import OAuth1Session

def create_session(self):
    if self.consumer_secret and self.consumer_key and self.access_token_secret and self.access_token:
        session = OAuth1Session(self.consumer_key,
            self.consumer_secret,
            self.access_token,
            self.access_token_secret,
            )
        self.session = session
    else:
        raise Exception("Need four creds for Quickbooks.create_session.")
    return self.session
```

What might I be missing here?

EDIT: current area of exploration is [here](https://github.com/litl/rauth/issues/109); I just formed the header you see (that has the "INCLUDE" string there) directly. Perhaps I should be using rauth to attach the file...

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see what code you're using with requests, I'm going to take a shot in the dark and tell you to remove setting your own `Content-Type`. You probably don't want that. It looks like you want `multipart/form-data` and requests will set that on its own if you stop fighting it.

---

It looks like you're missing the boundaries that QuickBooks is expecting (based on what you linked).

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_01"; filename="IMG_0771.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
<@INCLUDE *Y:\Documents\IMG_0771.jpg*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

The first and last line above seem to be what you're missing.

Comment: Thanks, @sigmavirus24. I believe I gave that a shot (without success). I added some code that hopefully shows you the code I'm using with requests; I'm happy to show more if you have another idea. I also tried without the Content-Type in the header AND without the Content-Type: application/pdf in the body (just in case that's what you meant).

Comment: @HaPsantran I've updated my answer since you updated your question

Comment: Check this post here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898976/upload-file-to-quickbooks-online-with-ids-v3

Comment: Thanks, both. I previously tried the boundaries without success. I believe I need to use requests module keywords (rather than try to generate the string) to get the result. Something like what's described in the multi-part encoded file section of [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Comment: I've posted the code [here](https://github.com/HaPsantran/quickbooks-python). Any ideas you might have would be appreciated. Thank you!